# php loop causing accordion panels to open all at once

Tags: javascript, php, accordion

I have a accordion panel that functions properly in it's html form, meaning that one tab at a time opens on click. But it was added to a php loop and now when you click on one tab and active class is added to them all causing them to open up all at once. Is there a way to fix this? I did not write the php code, a backend developer did, but he is not available at the moment to help me out with this.

Here what the code looks like
`

```
              for ($i = 0; $i < count($secs); $i++)
              {
                $sid = $secs[$i]->getid();
        // multiple replace due to conversion from plain textarea
        // to wysywig textarea (ckeditor); has to be "\r" & not '\r'
                $intro =
                str_replace("\r", "<br/>",
                    str_replace("<p>\r", "<p>",
                        (str_replace("</p>\r", "</p>",
                            $secs[$i]->getintro()))));

                if ((isset($intro) && ("x$intro" != "x")))
                {
                    ?>
            <section class="content large-8 columns">


              <p><?php echo $intro; ?></p>

              <?php
            }
          }
          $acsection = new acsection();
          $secs = $acsection->selectBy("((intro is null) or (length(intro) = 0)) "
           . "and user_id=".$ruid.
           " order by display_order,createdate");
           ?>
           <!-- <br/> -->
           <?php
           for ($i = 0; $i < count($secs); $i++)
           {
            $title = convert_smart_quotes($secs[$i]->gettitle(), 1);
          // multiple replace due to conversion from plain textarea
          // to wysywig textarea (ckeditor); has to be "\r" & not '\r'
            $content =
            str_replace("\r", "<br/>",
             str_replace("<p>\r", "<p>",
              (str_replace("</p>\r", "</p>",
               $secs[$i]->getcontent()))));
            if ((((isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) &&
                ($uid == $_SESSION['user_id'])) || //user or admin
             ((isset($_SESSION['admin']))
              && ($_SESSION['admin'] == 1)))
             && ($preview != 1))
            {
             ?>

             <div class="controls">
              <div class="delete">
               <a href="javascript:confirmDelete('manage-sections.php?sid=<?php echo $secs[$i]->getid(); ?>&uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>&cat=s&action=delete')">Delete current section</a>
             </div>
             <div class="edit">
               <a href="manage-sections.php?sid=<?php echo $secs[$i]->getid(); ?>&uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>&cat=s&action=edit">Edit current section</a>
             </div>
           </div>
           <?php
         }
         if ((isset($title) && ("x$title" != "x")))
         {
           ?>

           <dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
             <dd class="accordion-navigation">
              <a href="#panel1"><?php echo (isset($title) && ("x$title" != "x")) ? $title : "" ?></a>
              <div id="panel1" class="content" style="padding-left:3%;">
               <?php
             }
             if ((isset($content) && ("x$content" != "x")))
             {
               ?>
               <div class="content">
                <p class="accordin-content"><?php echo (isset($content) && ("x$content" != "x")) ? $content : "" ?></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </dd>
          <?php
        }
      }
      echo "\n";
  } // while
  ?>


</dl> <!-- End of Accordian Tabs -->
```

`

I am not very good with php or backend development so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is that each tab has the same id, so that when the active class gets applied to that id, it gets applied to all of them. Can we see the javascript as well?

Comment: @General_Twyckenham from how the code looks, yes, all panels seem to have id `#panel1`. In this case, appending `$i` to the id and href attributes should do it.
However, `isset($title) && ("x$title" != "x")` really looks like a nasty "workaround" for `isset($title) && strlen($title)` - or even simpler: `!empty($title)`.

Comment: @Lukas That may work. I've never really used `empty` myself so I can't promise that it will work as you describe. I'll just add my comment as an answer then :)

Comment: @General_Twyckenham: `No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. [...] The following things are considered to be empty: "" (an empty string) [...]` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: @Lukas Right I read that as well, so it sounds like it would be a good way to replace the 'hacky' code. I just have never personally used it (unlike `for` loops and duplicate id's which I've used/done extensively)

Comment: @Lukas Lol I just realized that you weren't the OP.

Comment: @General_Twyckenham thank you both for your comments. I have not been able to try the fixes out yet. But yes, what is happening is that once the accordion was put into the loop and one panel is clicked the active class is applied to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is that each tab has the same id, so that when the `active` class gets applied to that id, it gets applied to every tab.